# Show $H_{dR}^1(S^n)=0$ for $n>1$ without de-Rham Theorem, and some similar questions.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-forms

**Question**  Without using de Rham's theorem, prove:

(1)  Show $H_{dR}^1(S^n)=0$ for $n>1$.

(2)  Use (1) to show $H_{dR}^1(RP^n)=0$

(3)  a n-form $\Omega$ is exact on $S^n$ if and only if
$$ \int_{S^n}\,\Omega =0$$

(4) Use (3) to show that every smooth 2-form $\omega$ on $RP^2$ has the form $d \alpha $ for some smooth 1-form $\alpha$

I know I can prove $H_{dR}^1(S^n)=0$ by de-Rham theorem and Universal coefficient theorem. But perhaps we are expected to use some simpler tool to prove it.

Moreover, What I am really wondering is how to use (1) to prove (2) and use (3) to prove (4)?

Comment: (1) is likely asking you to prove directly that every closed $1$-form is also exact. As for (2), note that thanks to the canonical projection $\pi \colon S^n \to \Bbb{RP}^n$ you can lift every function defined on $\Bbb{RP}^n$ to a function defined on $S^n$. In particular, this holds for $1$-forms, so you're done if you can show that $\omega \circ \pi$ is closed when $\omega$ is closed.

Comment: Of course, a quick option for (1) is to use the [Mayer-Vietoris sequence](https://www.mn.uio.no/math/tjenester/kunnskap/kompendier/derham.pdf) for the de Rham cohomology, if you have that tool at your disposal.

Answer (score 5):

When $n>1$, $S^n$ is simply connected, and $H^1_{dR}(M) = 0$ for any simply connected manifold $M$. (Hint: For any closed $1$-form $\omega$ and any closed curve $\gamma$, we have $\displaystyle\int_\gamma\omega = 0$.)

Now, in order to deal with $\Bbb RP^n$, consider the $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ action given by the deck transformations. Show that any exact invariant $1$-form comes from an invariant function and hence descends to an exact $1$-form on $\Bbb RP^n$.

Comment: Thank you! But could you please give more detail about how to show any exact invariant 1-form comes from an invariant function?

Comment: Sure. Let $\alpha$ be the antipodal map of the sphere. If $\omega=df$ is an invariant exact $1$-form, we have $\alpha^*\omega = \omega$, so $d(f\circ\alpha) = df = \omega$. Thus, if we set $g = \frac12(f + f\circ\alpha)$, we see that $g$ is $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$-invariant and $dg = \omega$.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks for the answer - I learned a lot.